# Converting object to a Raster brick/Raster stack

Tags: r, rasterizing

After using rasterToPoints to create the matrix, is it possible to have the new object return to the original Raster Stack/Raster Brick form? My object is called "avghist" and has 138 values/layers, but I would like this to become a Raster Stack/Brick for other use. This is how avghist was created:

```
data("wrld_simpl")
b<-wrld_simpl

data("wrld_simpl")
b<-wrld_simpl

landhist <- mask(RCP1pctCO2Median,b)
histnew<-rasterToPoints(landhist)
weighthist <- cos(histnew[,"y"]*(pi/180))
histnew[,3:ncol(histnew)] = apply(histnew[,3:ncol(histnew)], 2, function(x) x  
* weighthist)
avghist <- colSums(histnew[,3:ncol(histnew)])/sum(weighthist)

avghist


head(avghist)

layer.1  layer.2  layer.3  layer.4  layer.5  layer.6 

52.75701 50.86984 49.91926 49.35157 52.78295 48.57297
```

"landhist" was already a Raster Brick but was converted to a matrix using rasterToPoints to eventually obtain "avghist". landhist looks like this:

```
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 64, 128, 8192, 138  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 2.8125, 2.789327  (x, y)
extent      : -181.4062, 178.5938, -89.25846, 89.25846  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       :   layer.1,   layer.2,   layer.3,   layer.4,   layer.5,   layer.6,   layer.7,     
layer.8,   layer.9,  layer.10,  layer.11,  layer.12,  layer.13,  layer.14,  layer.15, ... 
min values  :  52.88060,  54.93341,  55.79788,  54.18263,  53.85123,  55.68460,  50.17187,    
49.60006,  55.21446,  62.36937,  56.81446,  64.73854,  54.57714,  55.34295,  59.67952, ... 
max values  :  99.60231,  96.26976, 115.46164, 123.63807, 108.63827, 107.94791, 102.06677,   
102.09359, 132.50890, 138.31932, 101.19222,  97.19884, 115.07969, 131.96504, 120.14971, ...
```

To transform "avghist" into a rasterbrick, I attempted the following:

```
library(raster) 
newly<-rasterize(avghist)
```

Doing this, however, I receive this error:

```
"Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function   ‘rasterize’ for signature ‘"numeric", "missing"’
```

Why would this error emerge? To my understanding, the rasterize function should change avghist into a raster brick or stack, no?

This is what this as.raster(avghist/255) yields:

newly<-as.raster(avghist/255)

```
> print(newly)
     [,1]     
[1,] "#353535"
[2,] "#333333"
[3,] "#323232"
[4,] "#313131"
[5,] "#353535"
[6,] "#313131"
[7,] "#313131"
[8,] "#333333"
[9,] "#333333"
[10,] "#303030"
[11,] "#333333"
[12,] "#363636"
[13,] "#353535"
[14,] "#363636"
[15,] "#333333"
[16,] "#353535"
[17,] "#353535"
[18,] "#353535"
[19,] "#383838"
[20,] "#343434"
[21,] "#353535"
[22,] "#353535"
[23,] "#383838"
[24,] "#383838"
[25,] "#333333"
[26,] "#373737"
[27,] "#363636"
[28,] "#353535"
[29,] "#393939"
[30,] "#343434"
[31,] "#333333"
[32,] "#343434"
[33,] "#353535"
[34,] "#373737"
[35,] "#383838"
[36,] "#3D3D3D"
[37,] "#393939"
[38,] "#373737"
[39,] "#3C3C3C"
[40,] "#353535"
[41,] "#383838"
[42,] "#3C3C3C"
[43,] "#363636"
[44,] "#363636"
[45,] "#3B3B3B"
[46,] "#3B3B3B"
[47,] "#383838"
[48,] "#373737"
[49,] "#383838"
[50,] "#343434"
[51,] "#363636"
[52,] "#393939"
[53,] "#393939"
[54,] "#3C3C3C"
[55,] "#3D3D3D"
[56,] "#383838"
[57,] "#393939"
[58,] "#3B3B3B"
[59,] "#383838"
[60,] "#383838"
[61,] "#383838"
[62,] "#3E3E3E"
[63,] "#3B3B3B"
[64,] "#3C3C3C"
[65,] "#3E3E3E"
[66,] "#404040"
[67,] "#3F3F3F"
[68,] "#393939"
[69,] "#383838"
[70,] "#383838"
[71,] "#393939"
[72,] "#3C3C3C"
[73,] "#3F3F3F"
[74,] "#3B3B3B"
[75,] "#3E3E3E"
[76,] "#3A3A3A"
[77,] "#373737"
[78,] "#3A3A3A"
[79,] "#3E3E3E"
[80,] "#3E3E3E"
[81,] "#434343"
[82,] "#393939"
[83,] "#444444"
[84,] "#454545"
[85,] "#3C3C3C"
[86,] "#404040"
[87,] "#3E3E3E"
[88,] "#444444"
[89,] "#414141"
[90,] "#444444"
[91,] "#464646"
[92,] "#3F3F3F"
[93,] "#434343"
[94,] "#424242"
[95,] "#424242"
[96,] "#404040"
[97,] "#3C3C3C"
[98,] "#454545"
[99,] "#444444"
[100,] "#414141"
[101,] "#484848"
[102,] "#454545"
[103,] "#494949"
[104,] "#434343"
[105,] "#444444"
[106,] "#464646"
[107,] "#424242"
[108,] "#464646"
[109,] "#494949"
[110,] "#414141"
[111,] "#414141"
[112,] "#454545"
[113,] "#3E3E3E"
[114,] "#4B4B4B"
[115,] "#4A4A4A"
[116,] "#424242"
[117,] "#414141"
[118,] "#484848"
[119,] "#424242"
[120,] "#474747"
[121,] "#434343"
[122,] "#444444"
[123,] "#454545"
[124,] "#3F3F3F"
[125,] "#424242"
[126,] "#474747"
[127,] "#464646"
[128,] "#414141"
[129,] "#3E3E3E"
[130,] "#474747"
[131,] "#484848"
[132,] "#414141"
[133,] "#454545"
[134,] "#474747"
[135,] "#444444"
[136,] "#4C4C4C"
[137,] "#4F4F4F"
[138,] "#494949"
```

Is this now is rasterize format?

Thanks, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing `raster(avghist)` or `as.raster(avghist)`?

Comment: I tried raster(avghist), and I receive this error: "Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"numeric"’ ". When trying as.raster(avghist), I receive the error "Error in rgb(tx, tx, tx, maxColorValue = max) : 
  color intensity 52.757, not in [0,1] " Why would these errors appear when trying to rasterize this object? Thanks,

Comment: For the second error, you can patch it using `avghist/255` (raster uses colours in 0,1 instead of 0,255). The error you are getting is because of the format, you can typically make a raster from a matrix. Print out `avghist´ and comment the format. It's probably an nx1 array.

Comment: Indeed, that fixed the second error - I just added what avghist/255 looks like in my original post (please see edit above). Would this now be in raster brick/raster stack format? What I would like to do is plot the computed weighted values for each of the 8192 grid cells by averaging the 138 layers for each cell, and then plot this as a global map. Is that possible? I can do this with the original RasterBrick object "RCP1pctCO2Median", but I want to do this with the weighted values contained in avghist.

Comment: As i said, it's an nx1 array :). Just to be clear.. you know what a raster is? A raster is basically a georeferenced matrix (values for x/y pairs). A raster brick/stack is a set of rasters (for example, in an image, you can make a stack of 3 rasters where one is the red layer, another one the green layer and the last one the blue layer). So, you "can't" coarce a nx1 array into a raster. `avghist`, according to your code, is a colsum (an array with no "spatial" meaning), it doesn't have any mathematical signification trying to convert it to a raster.

Comment: thank you for the clarifications. Yes, that makes sense. In that case, would it be possible, using my above code to compute weighted values, to instead assign the weights to the original raster brick object "landhist" values, such that I have weighted values for each grid cell for each of the 138 raster layers? Thanks,

Comment: Well, you would have to build a matrix of the same dimensions containing that info for every cell, conver it to a raster and then add it to the previous brick/stack.